# Yii2 Formatear Atributos

Tags: yii

una consulta, hay alguna forma de formatear un atributo en el modelo ya sea antes de que se guarde o cuando se hace la consulta. La idea es que por ejemplo a la hora de traer una fecha, se formatee a un formato d-m-yy para poder utilizarlo directamente o en un caso contrario que un atributo descripción mas allá de si es un insert o update siempre ingrese con mayusculas. Si es posible podrían darme algún ejemplo? Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Para mostrar un atributo de un modelo previo formateo puedes en el modelo sobrescribir el método getAtributo

Si tienes una atributo llamado nombre y quieres que siempre salga en mayúsculas puedes en el modelo

> public function getNombre(){
>      return strtoupper($this->nombre);
>   }